# how to consolidate these loops

Tags: loops, kotlin

I know there has to be a way to make a loop to up the index by one. I haven't found a way without getting an error. I have fourteen if statements. I only put a few below.

```
 val className = readLine()!!.toUpperCase()
 val classNum = readLine()!!

 val pattern = """\s+\d+\s+$className.\s+$classNum\s.+\s+.+""".toRegex()
 val pattern2 = """\s{58}[a-zA-Z].+\s""".toRegex()

  for(i in 0..(lines.size-1) ) {

            var matchResult = pattern.find(lines[i])
            if (matchResult != null ) {
                // loop for 3rd line
               
                    if (pattern.containsMatchIn(lines[i])) {
                        println(lines[i])
                        if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[i + 1])) {
                            println(lines[i + 1])
                        }

                        if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[i + 2 ])) {
                            println(lines[i + 2])
                        }
                        if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[i + 3 ])) {
                            println(lines[i + 3])
                        }
                        if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[i + 4  ])) {
                            println(lines[i + 4])
                        }
                        if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[i + 5 ])) {
                            println(lines[i + 5])
                       {
                        }
            }
        }


    }while (className != "QUIT")
```

Comment: Can you describe what the code is intended to do?  (I can't tell whether it has misleading indentation, or missing/extra braces.)

Comment: Sorry. I am searching for a pattern and the first var pattern is for the first line match in the text file . Pattern2 is for the second line in the text file . I am trying to have pattern2 repeat if true and move to the next index.

Comment: Missing braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
for(i in 0..(lines.size-1) ) {

    var matchResult = pattern.find(lines[i])
    if (matchResult != null ) {

    // loop for 3rd line and more over 
        if (pattern.containsMatchIn(lines[i])) {
            println(lines[i])
        }
       
        for(k in (i+1)..(lines.size-1)) {    
            if (pattern2.containsMatchIn(lines[k])) {
                println(lines[k])
            }
        }
    }
}
```